# Django show render_to_response in template

Tags: python, django, view, render-to-response

Hello and thank you in advance.

I know this is total noob question, and I have searched in the various forum and read and re-read the documentation, so please be gentle.

I have a view:

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpResponseRedirect
from acme.acmetest.models import Player
from acme.acmetest.models import PickForm

def playerAdd(request, id=None):
    form = PickForm(request.POST or None,
                       instance=id and Player.objects.get(id=id))

    # Save new/edited pick
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/draft/')

    #return render_to_response('makepick.html', {'form':form})
    return render(request, 'makepick.html', {'form':form})

def draftShow(request):
    draft_list = ['1', 'hello', 'test', 'foo', 'bar']
    #draft_list = Player.objects.all()
    #return render_to_response('makepick.html', {'draft_list' :draft_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response('makepick.html', {'draft_list' :draft_list})
```

I am trying to get it to render to a template .html page:

```
#makepick.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<HTML lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Pick</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>{{ form }}</table>
        <input type="submit" value="Draft Player" 
    </form><br /><br /> 

Your picks so far:<br />
{% for draft in draft_list %}
    {{ draft.playernumber }}
{% endfor %}

</body>
</HTML>
```

Where playernumber is field in the model class "Player" in models.py.

```
#urls.py

from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from acme.acmetest import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^$', 'acme.acmetest.views.playerAdd'),
)
```

Thank you for your help!

dp

Comment: I get the HTML page, and other django code renders correctly on it, but all I get in the area I am writing now, is "your picks so far:" then nothing.  I would love it to show a list of player numbers from the draft list/model.

Comment: I can't spot any errors in your code ATM; try to debug it, e.g. via simple print statements (e.g. `print draft_list` before it goes to the template).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it looks like your template is rendering fine. So you'll have to see if `draft_list` actually contained anything and what `playernumber` is for each object that was grabbed.

In the root directory of your project, run:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Now that you're in the shell, to test whether there are actually any `Player` objects in your database and see what the `playernumber` property of each object returns:

```
from acme.acmetest.models import Player
draft_list = Player.objects.all()
for draft in draft_list:
    print draft.playernumber
```

Comment: @ U-DON thank you...Here are the results:`code`for draft in draft_list:

>>> for draft in draft_list:
...     print draft.playernumber
... 
23
21
24
174
1234
999
`code`

Comment: Kind of a shot in the dark, but try modifying your view to have this line: `return render_to_response('makepick.html', {'draft_list' :draft_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`.

Comment: Failing that, could you see what happens if you use another list, but with arbitrary values, and loop through it in the template?

Comment: I just tried this with the same result...`def draftShow(request):
    draft_list = ['1', 'hello', 'test', 'foo', 'bar']
    return render_to_response('makepick.html', {'draft_list' :draft_list})`  I am wondering if there is a problem with the other view I am feeding into the same html template.  I have a form that is using a `return HttpResponseRedirect('/draft/')` to return a response.  Note that `/draft/` actually calls the same page as we are starting on, but it is worth mentioning...

Comment: Is there another option other than using `render_to_response`?  All I really want to do is to show the items listed in the db that will update each time the table is updated.

Or is the problem on the HTML page `for loop`?

Comment: There is also `HttpResponse`, but that doesn't use the template. If you want to eventually show a substantial HTML page, you should probably rely on rendering a template. Can you show your `urls.py` file? And what's the URL you're using to access the page?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back...This is the URLS file for the app, the app..`from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from acme.acmetest import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^$', 'acme.acmetest.views.playerAdd'),
)
` Here is where it is called in the project urls...`from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   ('^$', include('acme.acmetest.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)`

Comment: As a tip, it would look cleaner if you just edit your original post and include any updates or new code there. Anyway, I don't see the `draftShow` view being matched to any URL in your app's `url.py`, but it should be if you want it to be accessible. Did you forget to include it here? If not, how were you able to access the page before?

Comment: Thank you for the tip and I am sorry for the difficult reading.  DraftShow isn't in urls.py.  I guess I am confused about urls.py.  How do I include it? I would like it called on the same template at the same url as the view playerAdd (which is included in the urls.py file.)

Comment: I have a feeling this whole problem lies in my views.py file.  I am re-printing my views.py file above in its entirety.  I think the problem is with how I am handling the responses of the two views....

Comment: OK...when I created a new html page with only the code that references the draftShow view, and called the page by going to the "/draft" url it worked.  I assume I have to create a new html "landing" page for each view then call THOSE to the template html page that visitors will access....

Comment: So has your problem been solved? Also, to answer your question about adding the URL to match to the draftShow view, it is very similar to the line `('^$', 'acme.acmetest.views.playerAdd'),`, but with `acme.acmetest.views.draftShow` being matched to something like `'^drafts/$'`. Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/.

Comment: Yes this problem has been solved, THANK YOU!!!Isit possible to have one URL call two separate views?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `makepick.hmtl` is in your apps `templates` directory, or in your TEMPLATE_DIR.

You can check in your view to verify that `Player.objects.all()` is actually returning something. Make sure playernumber is an actual property of the Player object.

Comment: makepick.html is in the TEMPLATE_DIR.  I have a form on that same page that is rendered correctly.  How can I check my view to see if Player.objects.all() is returning something?  playernumber is a property of the Player object in my models.py